# how to run a yeoman generator by running a index.js file like a normal node running

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Anyone using yeoman-generator, I have one query regarding running the generator without `yo` command. [this](https://bitbucket.org/anikethsaha/scaffold-generator/src/master/)  is my project here to run the package I have to use the command `yo trial` but I don't want that. I want something like running an `index.js` file to run the command. Any help with this? 
What I think it may be a workaround with `yeoman-environment` package but not sure about that.
I want my generator to run with a command something like

`node index.js`

and the generator should start.
It would be really helpful if any example is shared based on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I saw the docs and yeoman does support running the generators from node [HERE is docs](https://yeoman.io/authoring/integrating-yeoman.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can automate running `yo trial` from js files using npm packages like `execa` or `shelljs`.

```
// Example
// index.js

const execa = require("execa");

async function runTrial() {

  try{
    await execa.shell('yo trial');
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(error);
  }

}

runTrial();
```

Now, you can run `node index.js` which runs install function. But if you do this, you have to add `yo` and your generator as dependencies in `package.json` instead of asking users to install `yo` as global package.

Comment: This looks good. I am actualy looking for something with related to yeoman-generator. But this is fine as well. Will try this